# Styling part of pseudo-element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Is there some way I can target CSS styles at just part of the content of the :before and :after pseudo-elements?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/

Comment: What pseudo element? There are lot. What styling? And what do you mean by *just part of a pseudo-element*?

Comment: what is part of the content ? like :first-line

Comment: @mikakun - could be first-line, first-letter, embedded html... any technique that would allow me to apply different rules to different sections of the pseudo-element. For my particular use case first-letter would do, but I think the more general question is worth answering too

Comment: there is way to put html tags in the content (& therefore style attribute i imagine) but it's heavy & dirty; :after:first-letter ? never tried

Comment: @mikakun - yeah, I tried that and it doesn't work, which is annoying.

Comment: if u're not using :after & :before on same element you can dispatch content between the 2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `:before` pseudo-element content is displayed inline along with the content of the generating element, you can still target `:first-line` or `:first-letter` separately and it should override `:before` for the first line or letter of the generated content, respectively:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
}

div:before {
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.';
}

div:first-line { font-weight: bold; }
div:first-letter { color: red; }
```

Beyond that, you can't reliably target parts of `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements with CSS, as pseudo-elements cannot generate other pseudo-elements in CSS2.1, only real elements can. If you need to style the first letter of appended content, use JavaScript to append that content first.

Comment: Nice tip. Unfortunately I need to style the first letter of :after

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand when you say *just part of a pseudo-element*. To target styles for `:after` and `:before` treating them as block elements, the basic thing you need to have is:

```
.element:after, .element:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```